# In AngularJS, how can I remove an element created using $compile?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've written a simple example, where I create an element dynamically using $compile. This new element has another button, with which I want to remove this element (I've read that it is good to destroy scope/elements to avoid leaks). But the function closeThisElement() is not working; please help.

See plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/js7mpUMndjZEdMvRMuZk?p=preview

Also reproducing part of the code below:

```
link: function($scope, $element) {
    function closeThisElement(){
        $element.remove();
    }
    function addComment(){
        $element.append($compile('<div class="publishComment"><input type="text" ng-model="contentForReply"/><button ng-click="publishReply(contentForReply); closeThisElement()">Publish Reply</button></div>')($scope));
    }
    $scope.addComment = addComment;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have to be on the $scope. Currently they are just functions available to your link, but not within the html. Try this.

```
$scope.closeThisElement = closeThisElement;
```

To eliminate only the compiled component, save the instance and use that.

```
link: function($scope, $element) {
    var newElement;
    function closeThisElement(){
        newElement.remove();
    }
    function addComment(){
        newElement = $compile('<div class="publishComment"><input type="text" ng-model="contentForReply"/><button ng-click="publishReply(contentForReply); closeThisElement()">Publish Reply</button></div>')($scope);
        $element.append(newElement);
    }
    $scope.addComment = addComment;
    $scope.closeThisElement = closeThisElement;
}
```

It might be worth mentioning, that rather than creating and removing a new element, you could use ng-show or ng-hide and never have to compile it.

Comment: the problem is this links it to the parent's scope and the entire parent element gets eliminated. I just want the element created by $compile to be eliminated. I understand ng-repeat already is 'inheriting' scope, so setting, scope: true, shouldn't have any impact either. And if I isolate scope with scope: {}, it isn't working either. Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: I tried it with your updated code, but now, no element is getting removed. Yes, ng-show/hide is an option. But I'm really trying to understand scopes and compile. I have abstracted my more complicated problem I need to address into this simplified example here.

Comment: @KayaToast. My bad, I saved the element incorrectly. I fixed it, that should work now.

Comment: I tried again, see the new plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/d2XMH2N2YIUrErq7mG0w?p=preview but the element is not getting removed.

Comment: @KayaToast  change Angular to angular and it works perfect, or actually looks like it is already an angular element. better yet, take it out.

Answer (score 1):

The function closeThisElement needs to be part of the $scope for it to evaluate in your HTML:

`$scope.closeThisElement = closeThisElement;`

Though, the `$element` in Angular's link function refers to the directive element itself.

`$element.remove()` will remove the directive from the DOM. You can use `angular.element()` (alias to jQuery lite) to find the appended content and remove that to keep the tk-listview element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template` or `templateUrl` in directive configuration:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function(){
    return {
        // other configuration
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">' +
                       '<div>{{comment.hello}}</div>' +
                       '<button type="button" ng-click="removeComment(comment)"></button>' +
                   '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.comments = [{ hello: 'bonjour' }, { hello: 'konichiva' }];

            scope.removeComment = function(comment){
                scope.comments.splice(scope.comments.indexOf(comment), 1);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach. But I'm really trying to understand how scope and compile work. I want to understand, specifically, how can I remove this compiled element which is nesting inside of ng-repeat.

Comment: @KayaToast compiled element is actual string that is converted to jQuery element. It's not angularjs way to do things nicely

Comment: Seems strange if that is indeed the AngularJS way. Say, if I have 100 items in ng-repeat, and within that template, there are 2 links which can each create a directive, Then I need to pre-populate 200 elements. And if they are further nested, then even more so. And there is scope associated with each of them etc. Seems rather inefficient.

Comment: @KayaToast rerendering html is angularjs way, it's less performant but much more nice, structured and readable code. I think jQuery must be used when some particular task cannot be done with angularjs